# CSS. Change text color

Tags: css

So, I have following html.

```
<div id="a" class="a_button">
    <a class="a_link" href="#"> 

        <div class="icon_container">
            <img class="icon_image" src="#">
        </div>

        <div class="title_container"> 
            <span class="title_inactive">               
            Title
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>    
</div>
```

I am including an image to describe the situation better.
[image]

So, as you can see, this button is consisted of two `divs`: `icon_container` and `title_container`.

On mouse hover, the background color changes as planned.
Now, the color of `title` on `not-hover` is black and it should turn `white` when mouse is hovered.

And when mouse is hovered over the `title_container` div, the color changes from black and white (good).

However, when the mouse is hovered over the `icon_container`, the color of text does not change to white, even though the background color changes.

How can I make it so that when the mouse is hovered over the `icon_container`, it will cause the `title` color to be changed?

Here is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/8wfhnupk/5/

Thanks!

Comment: Add your code to codepen.io or jsfiddle.net along with the CSS you currently have.

Comment: Hi. I edited the question with jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you hover the `a` tag you need to change the color of the span in the title_container class.

Add this to your css :

```
a:hover .title_container span{
 color:#fff;   
}
```

or for the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wfhnupk/4/)

```
.royal_button a:hover .royal_menu_title{
 color:#fff;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Teedejee! =) I understand why it didn't work!

Comment: @steveKim I'm glad I could help you understand this part of css ;-) .

Answer (score 2):

add this to CSS:

```
 .title_container > .title_inactive:hover{color:white}
```

Comment: Whitespaces are allowed, surely they are 2 seperate classes

Comment: Thanks! =) I figured it out! :)

Comment: @JamesKing you're absolutely right (I don't know why I thought it was just one class)

Comment: =) no worries. I was not clear enough. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

alternatively you can use this,

```
<style>

.icon_container:hover{
color:#000;
background-color:#fff;
}
.title_container:hover{
color:#FFF;
background-color:green;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the solution:

```
.royal_button:hover div {
    color:#fff;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8wfhnupk/6/)

Answer (score -4):

```
<div class="title_container" style="color:red"> 
            <span class="title inactive">               
            Title
            </span>
        </div>
```

by applying inline style as shown above the text color will change.

Comment: Inline styles are always a bad idea

Comment: then add,color:red in class .title_inactive in the style.